# how can i make a program run sillently? (without the console window appearing)

Tags: winapi, console, window

For example, in C#, you can make a program run without the black screen appearing...so I thought: since anything you can do with .NET you can also do with Win32, maybe there's a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console window appears when the program is linked with `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` which is the default if you haven't asked for anything else.

If you want it to be a "Windows App" i.e. "make GUI contributions" including being invisible, link with `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`. However, you will need a `WinMain` function rather than the usual `main` function.

Comment: How can I do this? I entered:

#pragma comment (linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

, and replaced "int main()" with:

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)

, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: Two ways, as @Alex Farber suggests, you can do it via Visual Studio's properties editor - you're looking in Linker Settings for a C++ project. The other way is if you're building by hand, when you type "LINK /out:exename.exe obj1.obj obj2.obj" append /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS to that line.

Comment: You don't need to change main function to WinMain for this. At least, don't have to.

Comment: Thank you, indeed WinMain() wasn't necessary...i think it wasn't working for me before because i was working on an older compiler...I used Visual Studio and it worked now :-)

Answer (score 1):

Open Project - Properties, and set /SUBSYSTEM linker option to WINDOWS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a header file "MainEntryPoint.h" that contains the following text:

```
#pragma once
#if defined _MSC_VER 
  #if !defined _WINDLL
    #pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
  #endif
#endif
```

I #include this file in the main.cpp file of any project that

- needs to be a `windows` rather than console app
- As I do cross-platform work I prefer to use the standard (`main()`) C / C++ entry point for all my projects.

(The guard macro's automatically ensure it only applies to DevStudio builds and excludes messing with the entry point when building a dll).

Answer (score -1):

function:

start /b [command]